# Redis Lua scripting with large loops

Tags: lua, redis

Which of the following loops will run quicker in a Redis Lua Script for  10,000 iterations. Or will they both run at the same speed.

Does accessing a redis key inside a lua script take the same amount of time as accessing a local variable, e.g a value at a specific index of a table.

```
local members = redis.pcall('smembers','10000memberset')

for i=1,table.getN(members) do

 local value = members[i]
  -- do some logic on the value

end
```

or

```
for i=1,10000 do

  local value = redis.pcall('get',i) 
  -- do some logic on the value

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Guessing only, but I'd say that the loop will be more expensive

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't do expensive tasks in Lua, or you'll block the entire Redis server for miliseconds or even seconds..

Comment: `table.getn` is obsolete

Comment: #members is the new way

Comment: After testing with a 1,000,000 item set and 1,000,000 keys in redis the second loop is 6 times quicker. 20.5s vs 3.1s

Comment: I guess your Redis uses CLua and not LuaJIT, right? CLua works better with C calls because interpreted Lua is slower than machine code. LuaJIT works faster with Lua code because it effectively compiles it to highly optimized machine code - C calls break this. Furthermore fetching table size takes his time too and a loop with constant size results in better bytecode than one with variable size. And finally: has `members` not a field, like `n` for the table size? Good designers free users from this additional job.

Comment: To prevent blocking  your redis server  3.1 sec with the second loop, maybe you can setup a redis slave and perform it there.

Comment: > After testing with a 1,000,000 item set and 1,000,000 keys in redis the second loop is 6 times quicker. 20.5s vs 3.1s <- ok, that's not what **I** expected. I wonder what takes so much more time - is it the `redis.pcall` or accessing members table...

Comment: [several brain cycles later] it could be that the Lua allocation for `members` is what's killing performance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After testing with a 1,000,000 item set and 1,000,000 keys in redis the second loop is 6 times quicker. 20.5s vs 3.1s.